# Как вывести стихотворение из бд в первоначальном формате?

Tags: php, sql-server

Есть цель добавлять стихотворения в БД посредством PHP. Вопрос заключается в том, как сохранить исходное форматирование текста в БД или как вывести из БД полученные данные в первоначальном формате посредством PHP?

На данный момент в блоке

> Сижу за решеткой в темнице сырой.
>   Вскормленный в неволе орел молодой,
>   Мой грустный товарищ, махая крылом,
>   Кровавую пищу клюет под окном,

Мне же нужно вот так

> Сижу за решеткой в темнице сырой.
>   Вскормленный в неволе орел молодой,
>   Мой грустный товарищ, махая крылом,
>   Кровавую пищу клюет под окном,

Comment: Добавляйте с `html` разметкой и будет Ваша беда решена.

Comment: `nl2br()` Возможно вам это поможет

Comment: @DantheHat не всё так просто, как казалось бы. Стихотворения могут отправлять обычные пользователи. Поэтому вручную <br>-теги ставить в конце строк не катит.

Comment: @SNuSNuMR1996 ну тогда и в правду обрабатывайте `nl2br()`-ом строку, прежде чем засунуть в базу. Ну или как вариант - прикрутите к текстовому полю какой-нибудь `редактор`, который на автомате переписывает в `html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php) — Вставляет HTML-код разрыва строки перед каждым переводом строки

Comment: Благодарю! Заработало как нужно!

Answer (score 2):

1. Сказать браузеру не форматировать стих. Обернуть в <pre> тег или задать white-space: pre; для стиля(css) элемента в который выводиться стихотворение.
2. Как вариант можно использовать `nl2br`.

Но тогда такое не отформатируеш.

```
Дверь. На двери - 
          "Нельзя без доклада"
Под Марксом,
          в кресло вкресленный,
с высоким окладом,
          высок и гладок,
сидит
          облеченный ответственный.
...

    -- Владимир Маяковский
```

3. Самому писать умный парсер/форматировщик, но это может быть сложно.